# How to handle a file shared from another app to my own iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, share, url-scheme, uiapplicationdelegate

I follow the previous question ([Swift , Xcode, iOS - How to handle a file sent with 'Open in...' from another app to my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154366/swift-xcode-ios-how-to-handle-a-file-sent-with-open-in-from-another-ap)) to integrate the function to `Open in...` in my app. I would like to, for example, use the `Files` app to select a document file (e.g., PDF) and open in my own application.

However, the following code in `AppDelegate` does not get called. I wonder if this is because of the Swift's version difference? Apple changed the source code to do this for `iOS 15` or earlier versions? I would appreciate it if I could hear how to implement this in `Swift 5`, `iOS 15`.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                          options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        // Do something with the file
        print ("File was shared!")
        print (data)
       
        
    } catch {
        print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
    }

    return true
}
```

I have already set up the app in the way that other apps can attempt to share a file. When trying to open in my app, my app opens up, but the above code does not seem to be called.

Comment: Try to put code in `SceneDelegate.swift` class func `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {` and that will work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Kudos! I moved the entire of my posted code to the function at `SceneDelegate` following your comment; however, nothing happens... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you followed the approach from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154366/swift-xcode-ios-how-to-handle-a-file-sent-with-open-in-from-another-ap) only partially. In that case, the person had successfully implemented 2 of 3 parts of the solution for the custom URL scheme, so the answer only provided the 3rd part.

As https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app says:

> To support a custom URL scheme:
>
> 1. Define the format for your app’s URLs.
> 2. Register your scheme so that the system directs appropriate URLs to your app.
> 3. Handle the URLs that your app receives.

Their question was:

> My app is being displayed in the available applications to which I can send the file to. My question is what happens after? When I choose to send it to my app it then switches over to my app and from there, I don't know how to receive the file and read it to extract its content.

So they had already done steps 1 and 2 (so, their app was being displayed properly in the available applications, etc.).

In your case, it sounds like you haven't done steps 1 and 2 yet?

The other possibility is (also from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) if you are using Scenes, note that there are additional entry points to your app.

> If your app has opted into Scenes, and your app is not running, the system delivers the URL to the scene(*:willConnectTo:options:) delegate method after launch, and to scene(*:openURLContexts:) when your app opens a URL while running or suspended in memory.

Something like

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, 
       willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, 
       options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

// Determine who sent the URL.
if let urlContext = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first {

    let sendingAppID = urlContext.options.sourceApplication
    let url = urlContext.url
    print("source application = \(sendingAppID ?? "Unknown")")
    print("url = \(url)")

    // Process the URL similarly to the UIApplicationDelegate example.
}

/*
 *
 */
}
```

and as the Apple docs say, for the case the app is in the background, then implement something like

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>){
        let url = URLContexts.first?.url
        print("url = \(url)")

    // Process the URL similarly to the UIApplicationDelegate example.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, @auspicious99! I tried the example code you provided (by adding this to `SceneDelegate`), but it won't work when my app is running in the background. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I have added a sample function that will get called when the app is running in the background, rather than getting launched for handling the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for adding the code! WIth that, I was able to obtain the URL when the app is in background! I hope you have a great day today.

Comment: Glad to hear that, thanks for confirming that it worked. Have a great day too!

Answer (score 2):

The thing u are looking for is URL Schemes. You can open another app from currently opened app only when u have a registered url scheme for that app. If that app doesn't provide a URL scheme to open it, you can't.

Check the following examples:

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app
2. https://medium.com/@MdNiks/custom-url-scheme-deep-link-fa3e701a6295
3. https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

And, it is not possible to launch arbitrary application, but the native applications which registered the URL Schemes.

Comment: Thank you, @msusare, for your suggestion. I take a look at the website, quite informative, but unfortunately, I do not understand `object-C`. It would be great if I could have access to some information for `Swfit`.

Comment: Updated my answer you can find multiple examples of the same.

Comment: Thank you for adding updated resources, @msusare! I gave a look at all websites, and they are very useful and informative. One thing that I could not find was how `URL Schemes` can be used to share files across apps. I would like to open a file in the `Files` app in my original app, for example. Do you know any resources on that?